# Add Scrollbar to Combobox Java

Tags: java, swing, combobox, scrollbar

I have this code which is working very well but I have a little problem by adding the scrollbar in the popup of the combobox..
1. Doese anyone knows where the issue is? 
2. Is it also possible to add a filter to the combobox?

```
JComboBox<?> comboBox;
ComboBoxModel<?> model;
JTextComponent editor;


boolean selecting=false;
boolean hidePopupOnFocusLoss;
boolean hitBackspace=false;
boolean hitBackspaceOnSelection;

KeyListener editorKeyListener;
FocusListener editorFocusListener;

public AutoCompletion(final JComboBox<?> comboBox) {
    this.comboBox = comboBox;
    model = comboBox.getModel();
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!selecting) highlightCompletedText(0);
        }
    });
    comboBox.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            if (e.getPropertyName().equals("editor")) configureEditor((ComboBoxEditor) e.getNewValue());
            if (e.getPropertyName().equals("model")) model = (ComboBoxModel<?>) e.getNewValue();
        }
    });
    editorKeyListener = new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (comboBox.isDisplayable()) comboBox.setPopupVisible(true);
            hitBackspace=false;
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {

                case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE : hitBackspace=true;
                hitBackspaceOnSelection=editor.getSelectionStart()!=editor.getSelectionEnd();
                break;
                // ignore delete key
                case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE : e.consume();
                comboBox.getToolkit().beep();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    hidePopupOnFocusLoss=System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.5");

    editorFocusListener = new FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            highlightCompletedText(0);
        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

            if (hidePopupOnFocusLoss) comboBox.setPopupVisible(false);
        }
    };
    configureEditor(comboBox.getEditor());

    Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    if (selected!=null) setText(selected.toString());
    highlightCompletedText(0);
}

public static void enable(JComboBox<?> comboBox) {

    comboBox.setEditable(true);

    new AutoCompletion(comboBox);
}

void configureEditor(ComboBoxEditor newEditor) {
    if (editor != null) {
        editor.removeKeyListener(editorKeyListener);
        editor.removeFocusListener(editorFocusListener);
    }

    if (newEditor != null) {
        editor = (JTextComponent) newEditor.getEditorComponent();
        editor.addKeyListener(editorKeyListener);
        editor.addFocusListener(editorFocusListener);
        editor.setDocument(this);
    }
}

public void remove(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException {

    if (selecting) return;
    if (hitBackspace) {

        if (offs>0) {
            if (hitBackspaceOnSelection) offs--;
        } else {

            comboBox.getToolkit().beep(); 
        }
        highlightCompletedText(offs);
    } else {
        super.remove(offs, len);
    }
}

public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

    if (selecting) return;

    super.insertString(offs, str, a);

    Object item = lookupItem(getText(0, getLength()));
    if (item != null) {
        setSelectedItem(item);
    } else {

        item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();

        offs = offs-str.length();

        comboBox.getToolkit().beep(); 
    }
    setText(item.toString());

    highlightCompletedText(offs+str.length());
}

private void setText(String text) {
    try {

        super.remove(0, getLength());
        super.insertString(0, text, null);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
    }
}

private void highlightCompletedText(int start) {
    editor.setCaretPosition(getLength());
    editor.moveCaretPosition(start);
}

private void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
    selecting = true;
    model.setSelectedItem(item);
    selecting = false;
}

private Object lookupItem(String pattern) {
    Object selectedItem = model.getSelectedItem();

    if (selectedItem != null && startsWithIgnoreCase(selectedItem.toString(), pattern)) {
        return selectedItem;
    } else {

        for (int i=0, n=model.getSize(); i < n; i++) {
            Object currentItem = model.getElementAt(i);

            if (currentItem != null && startsWithIgnoreCase(currentItem.toString(), pattern)) {
                return currentItem;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}


private boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2) {
    return str1.toUpperCase().startsWith(str2.toUpperCase());
}
```

This is the code for the scrollbar:

```
public void adjustScrollBar(JComboBox<?> comboBox) {
    this.comboBox = comboBox;
    if (comboBox.getItemCount() == 0) return;
    Object comp = comboBox.getUI().getAccessibleChild(comboBox, 0);
    if (!(comp instanceof JPopupMenu)) {
        return;
    }
    JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu) comp;
    JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) popup.getComponent(0);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL));
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to add a horizontal scrollbar to the popup. If so then check out [Combo Box Popup](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/) for one solution.